# How to check records source in Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, bulk-api

The trigger must be developed. Inside I need to check are records came from outside SF via bulk load or they are created internally?

I can not change uploading process or modify records before they are uploaded.

All checks must be done inside a trigger.

How I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you create a specific User for this bulk load process that is not used for any other purpose. Then your trigger can base its conditional logic on that:

```
if (UserInfo.getUserName() == 'bulkloadprocess@abc.com')) ...
```

Comment: Good advice, but imagine this trigger will be a part of a managed package.
Also there will be a settings checkbox. If its checked then all bulk loaded records should be processed by the trigger, internal records not. if not checked then all records should not be processed by a trigger. 

Actually i can use this solution, and add setting for the user which will be used for loading records. 

Maybe we can find easier solution.

Comment: @DenisPereverzev Yes the custom setting could be the name or ID of the User that is special cased; if not set there would be no special casing.

Answer (score 2):

When you generally load data from outside using Dataloader it runs in a batch.

So the check you can apply is-

```
    if(System.isBatch()){
       //do this
    }else{
       //do this
    }
```

Note: If there are batches inside the system which are also making triggers run.Then also the code inside this condition will run.

Comment: @Frodo - Will Syste.isBatch=TRUE, If I am performing a DML operation on a list of records using apex.. or will it be true only if I perform Batch Job

Comment: @KAADI it will be true when this code executes from batch..